# Set minimum width for Bootstrap4 page and show scrolls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a website and it's not fully response - I accept it.
I want to set minimum width for overall page to something like `1000px` and display horizontal scrollbar if screen width is below this. I tried to use:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    min-width: 1000px !important;
  }
}
```

But it's not working, scrollbar appears but my DIVs getting messed. I'm using Bootstrap 4 with sass, is there any way to force this behavior?

Of course, I'll create fully responsive site later, but now I want to archieve this for mobile and tablets. Currently, my navbar under 1000px is totally broken.

EDIT: Example codepen with my navbar code, under 992px it gets broken: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJgGma

Comment: Any chance you can duplicate this in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: @DanielZuzevich check my post edit, I added codepen example

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you mean by your navbar being totally broken? Are you talking about how the menu appears below the search bar? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich yes, I want to force navbar to be in one line, and display horizontal scroll on all page if screen width is under 1000px (precisely 992px). I know it's not responsive, but I need this to fit rest of my page

Answer (score 0):

The elements in your nav always hit 100% width below 992px so they're going to wrap no matter what you do.

You need to define widths for your nav elements below 992 if you want it to stay at 1000px wide. Try setting them to percentages that equal 100% and you should be fine.